# Making each class a separate assembly

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I am not an experienced .Net programmer, hence this question.

Is it a terribly bad idea to put each (major) class in a separate assembly, so that whichever class's implementation I choose to change the executable need not be recompiled? Or does my idea imply serious performance issues due to runtime loading etc.?

I know the question is vague, but maybe there are specific guidelines as to what should be put in a separate assembly and what genereally shouldn't

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand how this will make deployment any easier. If you make a change to more than one class, you'll now have to deploy *more than one assembly*. Whereas, before, you could deploy all of your changes in a single assembly. If the question is whether you should split your library code into an assembly (DLL) separate from your executable (main assembly), then the answer is probably yes. But that's nowhere near the same thing as putting *each class* into a separate assembly. I feel like I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very bad idea.

- It will not save you compile-time.
- It will cost you run time.
- It will complicate your development
  and spend you a lot of your time.
- It will lead to bugs.
- Other mechanisms in the C# compiler take care of saving
  compile-time if you only change 1
  file (by the way one class per file
  is the standard - but there are some
  exceptions)

You need to put things in separate assemblies if you plan to redistribute them (install them to your end-users) as separate components. I'll bet that is not your scenario.

examples where you might split to assemblies:

- two entirely different programs - `clock.exe` and `facebookAlbumViewer.exe`
- 3-tier software: `MyProgramDataModel.dll`, `MyProgramBusinessLogic.dll` and `MyProgramGui.exe`
  in the future you ship a new `MyProgramDataModel.dll` (that now works with Oracle instead of MySql), so you deploy only that component. It will only make sense on big and complicated software.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea. Put concerns together in one assembly. But not a single class per assembly.
If you change two classes, you need to ship two assemblies instead of one. What have you won?

Answer (score 4):

You talk about client software.  A decent-sized project with a few hundred classes -> a few hundred DLLs is not acceptable for client software and this is not common practice.

Assemblies just aren't that big to worry about it.  With a DLL per class you'll be exposing all of your code structure - MyApp.dll, MyApp.MainForm.dll, MyApp.DatabaseLogic.UserAuthentication.dll -

Answer (score 2):

How much time will you save on compilation? How much time will you spend on adding a new project for each class?

Do not waste your time, let compiler do his job. Your time worth more than compiler's.

Comment: it's not about saving time on compilation. It's about easily updating client sofware by just shipping the assemblies

Comment: @Armen, ok, sorry for misunderstanding. Why do you think that shipping 1-5 assemblies will be easier than shipping of 1 executable file?

Comment: Hmm... didn't think of it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

If all of these classes you are talking about are doing different jobs and also can be seperated by the business they are doing then, putting each of them to seperate assembly is acceptable I suppose. However you also should be careful about this issue, else your applications might turn into a DLL hell!